# Java Annotation Processor getEnclosingElement() method

Tags: java, annotations, java-annotations

Hello，I would like to ask what is the meaning of the comments of the `getEnclosingElement()` method in the `Element` interface, I do not quite understand. javadoc  as follows：

> Returns the innermost element within which this element is, loosely speaking, enclosed.
>
> - If this element is one whose declaration is lexically enclosed immediately within the declaration of another element, that other element is returned.
> - If this is a **top-level** type, its package is returned.
> - If this is a **package**, null is returned.
> - If this is a **type parameter**, the generic element of the type parameter is returned.
> - If this is a **method or constructor parameter**, the executable element which declares the parameter is returned.

Annotations can be used on classes, variables (global or local), methods, etc., but I don't know the correspondence between annotations and Element subclass. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Element` can represent, as of Java 13:

- A module declaration - `ModuleElement`
- A package declaration - `PackageElement`
- An interface, class, enum, or annotation type - `TypeElement`
- A constructor, method, or initializer - `ExecutableElement`
- A field, enum constant, method or constructor parameter, local variable, resource variable, or exception parameter - `VariableElement`
- A type parameter - `TypeParameterElement`

Each of these elements can have annotations present. For example:

*module-info.java*:

```java
@Foobar
module example {
  exports com.example;
}
```

*package-info.java*:

```java
@Foobaz
package com.example;
```

*Foo.java*:

```java
package com.example;

@Baz
public class Foo<@Qux T> {

  private final T bar;

  public Foo(T bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Foo{bar= " + bar + "}";
  }
}
```

- The module `example`, which would be a `ModuleElement`, has a `@Foobar` annotation present.
- The package `com.example`, which would be a `PackageElement`, has a `@Foobaz` annotation present.
- The class `Foo`, which would be a `TypeElement`, has a `@Baz` annotation present.
- The type parameter `T`, which would be a `TypeParameterElement`, has a `@Qux` annotation present.
- The field `bar`, which would be a `VariableElement`, has no annotations present.
- The constructor `#Foo(T)`, which would be an `ExecutableElement`, has no annotations present.
- The constructor's parameter `bar`, which would be a `VariableElement`, has no annotations present.
- The method `#toString()`, which would be an `ExectuableElement`, has an `@Override` annotation present.

You can get the annotations present on these elements via the methods of the [`AnnotatedConstruct`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/AnnotatedConstruct.html) interface, which `Element` extends.

The method `Element#getEnclosingElement()` returns, unsurprisingly, the `Element` which encloses the current `Element`, if any. So if you were to invoke that method on the `ExecutableElement` representing the method `#toString()` then you'd get the `TypeElement` representing the class `Foo`.